# Prevent recursive event trigger on same table by knowing column name

Tags: sql, plpgsql

I have an event trigger defined for `ALTER TABLE`.
My use case is whenever there is update to schema using `ALTER TABLE`, I want to update the same table schema by dropping a column assume named as `secret`, and re-adding it with default values instead of updating the value of all rows.

This is causing nested calls : alter table for column `column1` -> triggering this event-trigger which drops column `secret` -> which agains trigger this event-trigger.

If I can get column name in event-trigger, I can stop this recursive calls.

Thanks!